# How to embed Eventbrite iframe/script in React component, JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eventbrite

The following is what Eventbrite provides is the 'embed code'.
How do I use it in my React component?

```
<div id="eventbrite-widget-container-12345678901"></div>

<script src="https://www.eventbrite.com/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var exampleCallback = function() {
        console.log('Order complete!');
    };

    window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
        // Required
        widgetType: 'checkout',
        eventId: '12345678901',
        iframeContainerId: 'eventbrite-widget-container-69831741619',

        // Optional
        iframeContainerHeight: 425,  // Widget height in pixels. Defaults to a minimum of 425px if not provided
        onOrderComplete: exampleCallback  // Method called when an order has successfully completed
    });
</script>
```